# Initialising when calling from another class

Tags: java, android

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {  

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);

        clear()

        return rootView;
    }    

    public void clear() {

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getPreferences(0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

If I want to call the method `clear()` from another class other than it's own `Tab1`, what do I need to initialise for it to work correctly because at the moment I get `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method` on line `SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getPreferences(0);` when calling from another class.

Comment: since it's an instance method, you'll need to initialize Tab1. Saying "I get an error" really isn't helpful. what kind of error are you getting?

Comment: I get `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method` but what do I need to initialise?

Comment: Is it the `View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);`?

Answer (score 0):

It may be `Activity` was not created .

Try this

```
protected Activity mActivity;


public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    this.mActivity = (Activity)context;
}
```

then use in your code .

```
public void clear() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mActivity.getPreferences(0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();
}
```